# Databricks - Displaying a Dataframe and printing a string

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to use one cell in databricks to display a dataframe and print some text underneath the display. I can't find anything on it on either the Databricks forum or here. It's a devilishly simple question so apologies if it is obvious.

myDF is a a pyspark.sql.dataframe

What I'm doing is:

```
myString = 'aasdf45'
print(myString)
display(myDF)
```

The output of the cell displays the DF, but the text isn't printed.

If I do this the other way around, printing the string after the display the result is still the same, showing the dataframe but no printed string:

```
myString = 'aasdf45'
display(myDF)
print(myString)
```

It seems like the behaviour is to display the DF over anything else. Is there a way I can show both? It's fine if not but it would be great to know.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as things stand with Databricks, you cannot combine a table display with other content. You'll have to put the other content in a separate cell before/after the cell output.

The only alternative for single cell output is quite complicated:

1. Collect the data you need to the driver using `df.collect()`.
2. Generate HTML for the content you need, e.g., build a `TABLE` from your data.
3. Use `displayHTML()`